# How do you write an array of numbers to a csv file?

Tags: csv, rust

```
let mut file = Writer::from_path(output_path)?;
file.write_record([5.34534536546, 34556.456456467567567, 345.56465456])?;
```

Produces the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `{float}: AsRef<[u8]>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:313:27
    |
313 |         file.write_record([5.34534536546, 34556.456456467567567, 345.56465456])?;
    |              ------------ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `{float}`
    |              |
    |              required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <&T as AsRef<U>>
              <&mut T as AsRef<U>>
              <Arc<T> as AsRef<T>>
              <Box<T, A> as AsRef<T>>
            and 44 others
note: required by a bound in `Writer::<W>::write_record`
   --> /home/mlueder/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/csv-1.1.6/src/writer.rs:896:12
    |
896 |         T: AsRef<[u8]>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Writer::<W>::write_record`
```

Is there any way to use the csv crate with numbers instead of structs or characters?

Comment: CSVs store text. Convert the numbers to strings. Rust is a *strongly-typed language*, so when you want to convert between different representations (for instance, an integer as a bit sequence and a base-10 string that looks like an integer), you have to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

Only strings or raw bytes can be written to a file; if you try to give it something else, it isn't sure how to handle the data (as @SilvioMayolo mentioned). You can map your float array to one with strings, and then you will be able to write the string array to the file.

```rust
let float_arr = [5.34534536546, 34556.456456467567567, 345.56465456];
let string_arr = float_arr.map(|e| e.to_string();
```

This can obviously be combined to one line without using the extra variable, but it is a little easier to see the extra step that we need to take if it is split apart.